# Vite Server is running on 127.0.0.1 by default instead of localhost

Tags: localhost, vite

Whenever i run `npm run dev`, i get vite running on domain 127.0.0.1 by default.

**How to make vite run on localhost instead?**

Theses are my configs:

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host=localhost",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  }
})
```

[image: vite console]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is intended. You can consult [vite localhost behavior](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host) (read the note).
To disable this behavior set `dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')` as explained there or upgrade Node.js to 17+. Also [localhost](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/127-0-0-1-localhost#:%7E:text=Localhost%20is%20the%20default%20name,to%20and%20communicate%20with%20itself.)

in your vite.config :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import dns from 'dns'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  }
})
```

Result:

[image: vite console]

Hope it answers to your question ! :)

Answer (score 6):

An **other alternative** solution that works:

package.json:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

vite.config.js:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  }
})
```

result:

[image: vite console]

[read more](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/8543)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from listening on the other network interfaces as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same problem and tried to use `dns.setDefaultResultOrder('verbatim')` solution but got TypeScript error:

```
Property 'setDefaultResultOrder' does not exist on type 'typeof import("dns")'
```

It's because I used Node 16 but have installed `@types/node` for Node 12. Just updated types package and everything is ok.

Also, I don't have to set `port: 'localhost'`, just `setDefaultResultOrder`.